# got stuck on fetching data in react js (using express, nodejs, json file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

OK guys, so I've been stuck with this thing for a while. I think I might be overlooking something or..I've got the react hooks wrong. Anything that you can point out on my code would be helpful and appreciated.

I am working on my todo app. The backend is here:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const {loadList} = require('./todolist');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

app.get('/todo', (req, res) => {
    res.send(loadList());
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

here is the json file:

```
{"title": "buy apples", "note": "1kg"},
{"title": "feed the cat", "note": "full bowl"}]
```

here is the app:

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import "./App.css"

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app-wrapper">
      <Header />
      <div>
        <Form />
      </div>
      <TodoList />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is the component i need help with:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const TodoList = () => {
    const [ todos, setTodos ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/todo')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setTodos(data.title))
    })

    return(
        <div>
            this is where the todolist should be
            {todos}
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoList;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't seem to have a question here. What steps have you taken to debug this? Are you getting any errors in the console? Why `setTodos(data.title)` and not `setTodos(data)`. Also maybe `useState([])` instead of `useState(null)`. And perhaps add a separate `if (!todos.length) return 'No data';`

Comment: oh, sorry. The question is "where is the problem" cause I didnt get any errors. It just doesnt appear anywhere. I tried to modify my code zillion times(also tried what you have mentioned). I tried different approaches (componentDidMount). Nothing worked so I do not know what to do next..

Comment: Are you receiving any data? Check the network tab in the dev tools and see what it says.

Comment: Couple of things to check. Is `./todolist` the actual name of your JSON file, or does it have an extension (like `./todolist.json`). Also, `console.log` the result of your `loadList()` call in your API to see if that file is actually being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what helped me: i realized ive had an array so i should iterate over to show every todo (starting with the title). so i guess i have to be more specific how i want my data to be showed.

```
this is where the todolist should be
            {todos.map((todo) => (
                <li className="list-item" key={todo.title}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={todo.title}
                        className={`list ${todo.completed ? "complete" : ""}`}
                        onChange={(event) => event.preventDefault()}
                    />
                </li>
            ))}
```